# How to work correctly update without form, from JSON REST api in symfony2

Tags: api, rest, symfony, insert-update

How to replace many to many joined table from REST API ?

Remove

```
foreach ($find_variant->getOptionValues() as $key => $option_data) {

$option = $em->getRepository('ISCoreBundle:OptionValue')->find($option_data->getId());

    if($option){
        $find_variant->removeOptionValue($option);
    }else{
        $this->json_status['status'] = 0;
        $this->json_status['message'] = 'Option Value not found!';
}
```

Update

```
foreach ($serilize->option as $key => $option_data) {
        // code...
        $option = $em->getRepository('ISCoreBundle:OptionValue')->find($option_data->id);

        if($option) {
            $find_variant->addOptionValue($option);
        } else {
            $this->json_status['status'] = 0;
            $this->json_status['message'] = 'Option Value not found!';
        }                                   
    }

}
```

I think it is an ugly way! What is correctly way?